# Salvar imagens em repositório e recuperá-la através de um Path com C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, arquivo

Como salvar imagens em repositório e recuperá-la através de um Path com Asp.Net MVC?

Pesquisando em alguns lugares, verifiquei que salvar imagens diretamente no banco de dados pode ter uma perda significativa de performance na aplicação.

Answer (score 2):

Segue exemplo de código de uma aplicação minha ASP.NET MVC5 e o pacote [ImageResizer](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ImageResizer/). Fiz um model chamado `ProductPicture` em que cada registro guarda a imagem de um produto e sua respectiva miniatura (*thumbnail*). As imagens e as miniaturas são guardadas dentro do diretório `Content` do site.

**Model**

```
public class ProductPicture
{
    [Key]
    public int ProductPictureId { get; set; }
    public int ProductId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "FileName", ResourceType = typeof(Resources.Language))]
    public String FileName { get; set; }

    public String Thumbnail { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Product", ResourceType = typeof(Resources.Language))]
    public virtual Product Product { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    [Display(Name = "File", ResourceType = typeof(Resources.Language))]
    public HttpPostedFileBase File { get; set; }

    public ProductPicture() { }

    public ProductPicture(int _ProductID) {
        this.ProductID = _ProductID;
    }
}
```

**Controller**

```
[HttpPost]
[Authorize(Roles = "Uploaders")]
public ActionResult Create(ProductPicture productpicture)
{
    // Se foi enviado um arquivo com mais do que 0 bytes:
    if (productpicture.File != null && productpicture.File.ContentLength > 0)
    {
        // Extraindo nome do arquivo
        var fileName = Path.GetFileName(productpicture.File.FileName);

        var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath(imagesDirectory), fileName);
        productpicture.File.SaveAs(path);

        productpicture.FileName = fileName;
        ModelState.Remove("FileName");

        // Thumbnails
        if (productpicture.File.ContentLength > 0)
        {
            ImageResizer.ImageJob i = new ImageResizer.ImageJob(productpicture.File, 
                imagesDirectory + "/Thumbnails/<guid>.<ext>", new ImageResizer.ResizeSettings(
                                        "width=250;height=250;format=jpg;mode=pad"));
            i.CreateParentDirectory = true; //Auto-create the uploads directory.
            i.Build();
            productpicture.Thumbnail = i.FinalPath.Split('\\').Last();
        }
    }

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        context.ProductPictures.Add(productpicture);
        context.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");  
    }

    // Se a validação falhar e a tela precisar ser recarregada
    ViewBag.PossibleProducts = context.Products;
    return View(productpicture);
}
```

**View**
_CreateOrEdit.cshtml

```
@model MyProject.Models.ProductPicture
@using MyProject.Models
@using MyProject.Resources

<div class="editor-label">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.File)
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.File, new { type = "file" })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.File)
</div>
<div class="editor-label">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Product)
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.ProductId, ((IEnumerable<Product>)ViewBag.PossibleProducts).Select(option => new SelectListItem {
        Text = (option == null ? "None" : option.Name), 
        Value = option.ProductId.ToString(),
        Selected = (Model != null) && (option.ProductId == Model.ProductId)
    }), Language.Choose)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ProductId)
</div>
```

**View**
Create.cshtml

```
@model MyProject.Models.ProductPicture
@using MyProject.Resources

@{
    ViewBag.Title = Language.Create;
}

<h2>@Language.Create</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "ProductPictures", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" })) {
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <fieldset>
        <legend>@Language.ProductPicture</legend>
            @Html.Partial("_CreateOrEdit", Model)
        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="@Language.Create" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink(Language.BackToList, "Index")
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Uma alternativa é gravar apenas o caminho do arquivo no banco de dados (Path).
Tendo em mãos o Path da imagem, carregado a partir do banco de dados, é possível fazer da seguinte forma:

```
private static BitmapImage LoadImage(String arquivo)
{
    try
    {
            if (System.IO.File.Exists(arquivo))
            {

                Uri urlImg = new Uri(arquivo, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);

                return new BitmapImage(urlImg);
            }
            else
                return null;

    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        throw;
    }
}
```

Aí basta chamar:

```
LoadImage("..\imagens\xxx.png");
```